# When I pull soccer data into a data frame , I want to be able to calculate th average goals scored , excluding the current match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i want to create a new column with the average goals of the home teams in previous 2 matches.

```
  Home Team   Away Team   Htgs   Atgs  
 ----------- ----------- ------ ------ 
  Resita      Bozovici       1      3  
  Dalboset    Sopot          5      2  
  Calnic      Craiova        7      3  
  Bozovici    Calnic         6      1  
  Sopot       Bozovici       2      0  
  Resita      Sopot          3      2
```

first i am sorting the index( reversing the row's)

```
df = df.sort_index(ascending=False, axis=0)



     Home Team   Away Team   Htgs   Atgs  
 ---- ----------- ----------- ------ ------ 
  34   Calnic      Dinamo         0      2  
  33   Buzau       Braila         3      5  
  32   Dalboset    Calnic         2      3  
  31   Resita      Dalboset       2      0
```

now i write the code to get the average goals of all the teams in the 'Home Team' column for the previous 2 games .

```
df['Htgs/3'] = (df.groupby('Home Team' ) 
['Htgs'].rolling(window=2).mean().reset_index(0,drop=True))
```

this code is good but is not what i need cause the program iterate thru the first match and gives Nan then goes to the second match and writes the average of these matches and i need it to go to the third match and in this row to write the average of the first 2.

so i tried this code but the output is a total mess, no idea what the heck it has calculated.

```
df['Htgs/3'] = (df.groupby('Home Team')
 ['Htgs'].rolling(window=2).mean().shift(1).reset_index(0,drop=True))
df

Output :Htgs/3
```

it should be Nan until the second Resita and next is Sopot with 3.5 which is correct cause in the previous two matches they scored 7 goals.
      i don't understand what is the issue hier, if somebody could please help me fix this...

```
       Home Team   Away Team   Htgs   Atgs   Htgs/3  
 ---- ----------- ----------- ------ ------ -------- 
  34   Calnic      Dinamo         0      2   1.0     
  33   Buzau       Braila         3      5   5.0     
  32   Dalboset    Calnic         2      3   2.0     
  31   Resita      Dalboset       2      0   3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that you're using column-vector or row-vector operations to perform a static operation.  You already found the column-vector problem, which is that you start with an invalid column figure.  The second attempt shifts the rows by one, such that you're averaging the goals of two different teams.

Write a simple, static expression for the mean of the last two figures in the column: not a rolling average, not a shift -- just a simple `(last + last_but_one)/2` expression.  *That* is something you can vectorize for all rows.

There are many examples on Stack Overflow of creating a new column based on values in other columns; use one of those.  Alter the expression to use the last two data in your home-goals columns.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: I'm impressed you were able to make sense of that post without code blocks!

Comment: thank for your input ,i will search and try to figure out the solution.

Comment: still no solution,can you give me some more help please?

Comment: "Some more help" is far too general.  What did you accomplish in your searches?  Would a `groupby` on each team help you gather the two matches you need?

Comment: i think a weighted moving average would help me, with weights 1,1,0. this way the match number 3 will not count in the average,but i have no idea how to implement that.

Comment: One of my points is that you do not have a *moving* average: you want only the most recent two matches.

Comment: i want for all the matches to have those averages. from the first match in the table to the last, even if the first 2 of every team wil be Nan,i have no ideea how could this be done if not with moving average

Comment: Use `groupby` to partition the results by home team.  For each group, average the two latest entries by direct indexing (rows 0 and 1).

Comment: no idea how to do that, instead i did this:                                                                           f['Htgs/3'] = df.groupby('Home Team', ) ['Htgs'].rolling(window=3, min_periods=3 ).mean().reset_index(0,drop=True),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
                                                                                                        
df['Htgs/3']= ((df['Htgs/3'] * 3) - df['Htgs']) / 2            i got the result i need

Comment: Great.  Please consider writing up that as an answer and accepting it.  That will allow SO to properly retire your question.